# Distributing python modules for another architecture

Tags: python, architecture, pyqt

I'm wondering how I can create a 32-bit binary with my 64bit cx_freeze. I've looked at the [homepage](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/cx_Freeze.html) and I can't find a setting to tell it what architecture to build for.

I'm running 32bit(otherwise PyQt won't work) Python 2.6, so the dependencies should already be 32bit, on 64bit Kubuntu 10.10.

Comment: Since Python source runs everyone, what's wrong with simply distributing source?

Comment: If I need to distribute source I need to distribute PyQt, python-crypto and all the other dependencies as well. The users are kind of non-savy when it comes to computers so I want to make the installation as easy as possible, i.e. ship all the binaries needed in the installation. That part is done, it works. I just need to build it for 32bit as well as 64bit.

Comment: `easy_install` doesn't work for them?

Comment: Googled a bit and easy_install seem to be a python module, my employer doesn't want people to have to install python. I need to create a seperate binary distribution. Thanks for the tip though, will probably come in hand at some other point :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were using Windows or a Mac, then you could use `py2exe` or `py2app`, respectively. I think that [freeze](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Freeze) *may* be a more general solution that may work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this link will help you: http://linux.die.net/man/8/linux32
Otherwise you can create a x32 virtual machine by using QEmu or VirtualBox...

Answer (score 0):

I have a pyqt project for which I used to distribute frozen apps before just releasing it open source, for win/linux/osx.

I used the following:

- Pyinstaller for linux
- Py2app for osx
- Py2exe for windows

http://www.pyinstaller.org/